# Website copies more text than I highlighted to the clipboard

Tags: html, css, copy-paste

I was really surprised earlier when I highlighted and copied some text from a website and then pasted it, the text I pasted included something I didn't copy!

I tried it with other parts of the text, and each time, `pasting` included a blurb that I didn't highlight!

The website in question is: http://www.mars-one.com/about-mars-one

When I highlighted the first paragraph and pasted it into Notepad, I saw an extra line saying:

`See more at: http://www.mars-one.com/about-mars-one#sthash.pRl6tbqo.dpuf`

How did they do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution: http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a><br />Copyright &copy; c.bavota"; // change this if you want
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position='absolute';
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a summary of the link or maybe some code in your answer.